# Change the orientation only for specific view controllers in ios swift 2.3 and swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, swift2, uiinterfaceorientation

I was `searching` that how can I change the `orientation` to `LandScape` mode only for `spefic view controller` when the `Device Orientation` is  set to `Portrait` in the project `settings`. Didn't get any succesfull result. so finally I found a way to do it.

this is project device orientation looks like ....

[image]

**In swift 2.3 add following methods**

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.LandscapeLeft
    }


    override func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {
        return UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft
    }
```

**For swift 3.0 do like below ....**

```
  override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return false
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .landscapeLeft
    }

    override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
        return .landscapeLeft
    }
```

> **Note :This will work fine, if you navigate from one view to another view controller without a navigation controller .**

for more see this small video tutorial : [change device orientation for specific view controller in ios](https://youtu.be/4P_OWIE1CGk)

if anyone has better way  to do this or comments  , hope your answer or comments  here . thanx .

Comment: addition to the answer - Even if you modally present with some custom transition style, layout orientation change will not work.

Comment: hello. how will i do if i want to return both potrait and lanscapeLeft, as I want to play video in both mode

Answer (score 1):

Use **supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor** application delegate.add following code in **AppDelegate** file

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

            if isIpadLandscape {
                 return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all;
            }else{
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait;

            }


    }


Add particular **viewcontroller** page you want to **rotate**

     override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            isLandscape = true
    }
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
            isLandscape = false
        }
```

And dont forget to add global varibale in appdelegate file

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Foundation
    var isLandscape = false
    @UIApplicationMain
```