# Orientation support in single view controller swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I need to orientation support in single view controller

I try but did not work. Right now orientation in whole app.

[image]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.lockOrientation()
}

func lockOrientation() {
    let orientationValue = UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue
    UIDevice.current.setValue(orientationValue, forKey: "orientation")
}

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return false
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .portrait
}

override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return .portrait
}
```

Comment: That `UIDevice` line is a bad idea. It's a crash waiting to happen.

Comment: @rmaddy thank your for your comment, Can you please provide sample code which is working very well, Do you have any solution ?

Comment: Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42665450/change-the-orientation-only-for-specific-view-controllers-in-ios-swift-2-3-and-s/42666574#42666574

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to lock orientation of one view controller to portrait mode only in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938660/how-to-lock-orientation-of-one-view-controller-to-portrait-mode-only-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

Put the below code in `AppDelegate`

Keep **Device Orientation** as **Portrait** only from Project General settings

```
var restrictRotation: Bool = true

func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if restrictRotation {
        return .portrait
    } else {
        return .all
    }
}
```

Put below code in which you want to allow/disable orientation.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.restrictRotation(false) //TRUE TO RESTRICT ORIENTATION && FALSE TO ALLOW ORIENTATION
}

func restrictRotation(_ restriction: Bool) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    appDelegate?.restrictRotation = restriction
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved with [bmjohns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938660/how-to-lock-orientation-of-one-view-controller-to-portrait-mode-only-in-swift) answer
Please visit and check this.

@bmjohns answer updated version

## Swift 5

```
// set orientations you want to be allowed in this property by default
var orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all

func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        self.lockOrientation()
        return true
}

func unlockOriention () {
    self.orientationLock = .all
}

func lockOrientation() {
    self.orientationLock = .portrait
}
```

**SecondViewController.swift**

> While support orientation

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.unlockOriention()
    }
```